# Unity | How to create C# classes with different properties like Objects in javascript and put them in an array?

Tags: unity, c#

I just started my gamedev journey on unity this week and while I have a background with coding, I'm still somewhat of a beginner. Last year I made a text/UI based game on the web browser with javascript and have been trying to make the same game on Unity.

One of the main features of my game is that you press a button to "go hunting" and I had an array filled with enemies that were objects with different properties such as health, mana, attack, etc...

Then I'd randomly pick one of those objects from the array to be chosen as my enemy that I'd fight. I've been trying to figure out the best way to do this with C# and I might just be overthinking this.

As a bonus, I'd also like to be able to see the individual enemy objects in the array in my inspector if possible so I could tweak the stats within unity.

I've looked at scriptableObjects and different things but I am having a hard time putting it all together in an array from within unity.

```
[System.Serializable]
public class playerClass
{
    public string playerName;
    public int lvl;
    public int maxHealth;
    public int health;
    public int maxEnergy;
    public int energy;
    public int exp;
}

public class playerScript : MonoBehaviour
{
    public playerClass player;

}
```

This is how I created an object for the player, I want to do something similar for the enemies but put them in an array so I could randomly pick from them.

If there is a better way to do this I'd also welcome some advice :) thank you

Comment: It looks like you've got the basics down. How have you tried putting these objects into an array so far? Did you run into a specific problem along the way?

Comment: @DMGregory putting it into an array is where I am having some difficulty, the syntax is throwing me off a little bit. I am also wondering if making the enemies individual unity objects makes sense? That way I have more control within the inspector

Comment: By the syntax of an array, you mean something like `public playerClass[] playerParameterVariants;` ? Where specifically is that throwing you off?

Comment: @DMGregory I mean where exactly do I populate the data? Would it be within the array bracket? like public playerClass [enemy1, enemy2, enemy3] then where would I specify the different stats between them?

Comment: Would you not populate this data in the Inspector, rather than in your code?

Comment: @DMGregory Wow, that was way easier than I thought. That's exactly what I wanted. Thank you very much:) I didn't think to look in the inspector.

Comment: If you've found a satisfactory solution to your problem, please document it as an Answer below — it might help other developers solving similar problems in the future.